# Add a drop down in a IBM BPM Table column based on some condition

Tags: ibm-bpm

In a particular column of a table there could be either a drop down or a output text field based on the value in another field of that table. Say a table has two columns: Property and Value. If the Property field has a value say size, then the Value field should show a drop down to select the size. If the property field has a value say price then a output text field should be there. How can we achieve that in IBM BPM coaches?

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this if you are using table from SPARK UI TOOKLITS.

In case of BPM Coaches table, then I would suggest to create a custom coach view for table in basic html and get the value of dropdown in config option variable, then based on the requirement logic, you can frame the table and columns accordingly